# Should I add __init__.py to a git repository?

Tags: python, git, module

There is a similar question dealing with github but the answers concentrate on the "how".
This question is different.

I have some python code and some folders that are modules. To run it requires that a `__init__.py`.

My question is, should I include this (empty) file in the git repo?

Comment: If it's required to run, then yes. Init files are normal part of python project structure, even if they are empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

One of the main reasones for the `__init__.py` file is to let python know that a directory in your project structure can be treated as a package where modules can be be found and then imported. `The __init__.py` file can hold other data but in the case of an empty file its purpose would be to allow imports

If you were to not include this and your repo was cloned into a different location, all the imports of those specific packages and modules where the `__init__.py` is not present, will fail to import and your code will not work.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages

Comment: Technically it's more complex. `__init__.py` is the best practice (and I fully support it) but it's not strictly necessary. In some rare advanced cases, it's useful [not to use it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#examples). To convince you it's possible, test it yourself: `mkdir foo; echo 'print("bar")' > foo/bar.py; python3 -c 'import foo.bar'`

Comment: Thank you for sharing that..I was not aware about that functionality with nested namespace packages.